# Communication Between Different Services in Kubernetes Deploy

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm new to using Kubernetes (v 1.11.2-gke.18), and am trying to get Sentry running as a Kubernetes deployment. This is all being run in Google Cloud. Here's the YAML files for Postgres, Redis, and Sentry:

[image: postgres.yml for k8s]
[image: redis.yml for k8s]
[image: sentry.yml for k8s]

The Redis and Postgres parts seem to be up and running just fine, but Sentry fails because: `could not translate host name "postgres-sentry:5432" to address: Name or service not known`.

My question is this: How do I get these services to communicate properly? How do I get the Sentry container to communicate with Postgres and Redis?

Comment: It is not really good way, to post code as images. Here is a link with examples of markdown, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that in this case, what I needed was to change the SENTRY_REDIS_HOST and SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST values to not have the port numbers in the env declaration. Taking those out made everything talk together as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes pods generally can find other pods through services using [DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

Your configuration looks correct if `postgres-sentry` is in the same namespace as your sentry app pod/deployment (which looks like the default namespace).

So it points that you may have a problem with DNS. You can check by shelling into the sentry app container/pod and trying to ping `postgres-sentry`:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <pod-id-of-your-sentry-app> sh
# ping postgres-sentry
```

Also, check if you have you `/etc/resolv.conf` looks something like this:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Finally, check if your DNS pods are running:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep dns
coredns-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx                                             1/1     Running   15         116d
coredns-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx                                             1/1     Running   15         116d
```

Comment: The DNS pods are running, it doesn't look like we have a file at /etc/resolve.conf, and I can't shell into the sentry pod because it doesn't start. It goes up for a second, then crashes.

Comment: Try creating another dummy pod with a known container image like 'ubuntu' that has a shell and then try pinging from there on the same namespace